# How to select a parent div in html using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Given the following code:

```
  <div class="parent">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2">
<div>Elemnt is here</div>
</div>
    </div>

 $("#rembook").live('click', function () {

            var cur = $(this);
            var ID = cur.attr('class').substring(4);
                    cur.parent('.div').fadeOut('slow');

            });
```

I want to hide the parent div when someone clicks on them.
The code I use to hide does not work. Are there any other tricks to do this well in jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

If that was your exact code there are several mistakes.

`$("#rembook")` this will not select anything as there aren't any object in the HTML with the `rembook` id.

Considering it was just a mistake here in the example (where I guess it should be #div1, or #div2), another problem is

```
cur.attr('class').substring(4)
```

The `cur` variiable, which should be `div1`, doesn't have a class attribute, so `cur.attr('class')` will be empty, and `cur.attr('class').substring(4)` will throw an error which will stop you JavaScript code from working.

Finally, this part of the code `cur.parent('.div')` will not select anything as you are the selecting the parent element that has a class `div` (example `<div class='div>`) where it should have been

```
cur.parent('div').fadeOut('slow');
```

Or just

```
cur.parent().fadeOut('slow');
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `#rembook` is not in your example code, so I see no reason why it's expected to work.

Second, other than `parent()` there's a chance that you might need `closest()`, in case the element you need to hide is not an immediate parent and is located further up the dom tree.

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
$(this).parent()
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your HTML Code like this :

```
<div class="parent">
  <div id="div1">Test</div>
  <div id="div2">Test</div>
  <div id="rembook">Button</div>
</div>
```

and your question is to hide parent of ID rembook.

You can use parent method:

```
 $("#rembook").live('click', function () {

        var cur = $(this);            
                cur.parent().fadeOut('slow');

        });
```

Hope it can help..

Answer (score 0):

did you try `$.parent("div1")`